# SAPUI5 me:calendar how get the selected date when i go back?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

im try something around but it doesnt want to work :D.. so maybe you can help?

the calendar from

```
<me:Calendar id="WEEKLY_CALENDAR" swipeToNavigate="true" design="Approval" singleRow="true" weeksPerRow="2" hideNavControls="false"
                        tapOnDate="onSelect"></me:Calendar>
```

(I know its deprecated but i need him to use because of his style the one row style)

For example: i pick a date go to other page and come back with the back button.. it always set it on the current date.. but i want that it set on the date which i picked before? is there a way?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i got it.. it was nighttime and my brain dosent worked very well... i just pass the date from the page before to the odata.read method with the filter